# Is this a wrong sentence "Heidi Montag is probably more famous for the plastic surgery that she has had carried out than for her TV Career"?

Tags: sentence-construction

This sentence is literally copied from an English textbook (Solutions 2nd Edition -Intermediate)

"*Heidi Montag is probably more famous for the plastic surgery that she **has had carried out** than for her TV Career*"?

Does it say "**She has had the plastic surgery carried out**"?

Comment: I can't really answer because I'm not sure why but, as a native English speaker, I would never use the verb "carry out" with "plastic surgery". This sentence is much more naturally stated as, "Heidi Montag is probably more famous for the plastic surgery that she has had than for her TV Career."  In my experience, people "get plastic surgery," or "have had plastic surgery." and doctors "perform plastic surgery."

Comment: From Wikipedia: [In January 2010, Montag revealed to People that she had undergone ten cosmetic surgery procedures in a single day two months prior, performed by Frank Ryan.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heidi_Montag)

Answer (score 1):

doctors **carry out surgical procedures**. The does collocate properly here.

A person can be said to have had a surgical procedure carried out on himself or herself.

**has had done [on her] would have been better. In every day speech.**

However, to have had carried [on her] is fine. Notice the passive tense:

She has had them carried out [by a surgeon].

Answer (score 1):

> Does it say "She has had the plastic surgery carried out"?

Yes

The verb is in the causative passive voice.

"Heidi Montag is probably more famous for the plastic surgery that she has had..." =

"Heidi Montag is probably more famous for the plastic surgery that she has arranged for surgeons to carry out on her in the past."

(I see there are objections to "**carry out**", but I can't see anything wrong with it. Surgeons regularly "carry out" operations.)

Comment: "carry out" is not ungrammatical, but it is unindiomatic.

Comment: Not in British English.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a wrong sentence, but it is perhaps not the most conventional phrasing.
Surgeries, plastic or otherwise, tend to be '**undergone**' rather than '**carried out**'.
At least when you're talking about the patient and not the surgeon.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is not grammatically incorrect but has been written by a non-native and is not colloquial or idiomatic to native prose.  The issue is with the use of carry out.